# Did each tribe of Israel serve a specific purpose?

Tags: shevatim-12-tribes

I understand that the tribe of Levi were Priests, and the tribe of Benjamin were solders (Slingers to be more specific).  But is there a general trait that is distinguished in each of the twelve (12) tribes of Israel?

Comment: Judah (kingship), Issachar (scholarship), and Zevulon (international trade) have pretty well defined roles in tradition. The other tribes, less so, though Ephraim is pretty clearly a counterbalance to Judah.

Answer (score 1):

> Reuben – The First
>     Shimeon – The Aggressor
>     Levi – The priest
>     Judah – The Leader
>     Dan – The Judge
>     Naphtali – The Free Spirit
>     Gad – The Warrior
>     Asher – The Prosperous One
>     Issachar – The Scholar
>     Zebulun – The Businessperson
>     Joseph – The Sufferer
>     Menashe – Reconnection
>     Ephraim – Transformation
>     Benjamin – The Ravenous Consumer

From [here](http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1717386/jewish/Twelve-Tribes-Twelve-Paths.htm).